# SQL query returns output in tuple with missing key (column name) in {key:value} pair

Tags: python

I want to retrieve data from database table in a key:value format. But by using a SQL query, I'm only getting value in tuple format.

Here is my code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `stock_" + str(
            user_id) + "` INNER JOIN product ON stock_" + str(
            user_id) + ".product_id=product.id WHERE product.category=" + category + 
            " AND product.sub_category =" + sub_category

cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(records)
```

And heres the output:

```
(11, datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 2, 7, 59),10,500,400,100,20.0)
```

and my expected Output:

```
{
            "id": 11,
            "expiry_date": "2020-07-01",
            "quantity": 10,
            "mrp": 500,
            "selling_price": 400,
            "discount_prize": 100,
            "discount_percent": 20.0
}
```

Comment: Why do expect that output? `fetchall` returns a list of tuples.

Comment: okay. is there any other way around? i want output with its corresponding column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cursor.description` to get the field names and you could then use a list comprehension to create a list of dictionaries with the results from the query.

That should give you something close to your desired output.

```py
records = cursor.fetchall()

fields = [field[0] for field in cursor.description]

data = [dict(zip(fields, record))  for record in records]
```